# Does this integral converge when $p<0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does this integral converge when $p<0$?

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \sin(x^p)\ dx$$

Comment: For next time, show whether or not you have attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the substitution $y=x^{p}$. $\int_0 ^{\infty} y^{-1+\frac 1 p} \sin y dy$ converges if and only if $\int_0 ^{1} y^{-1+\frac 1 p} y dy$ converges which is true if and only if $1+\frac 1p >0$, i.e. $p<-1$. I have used the fact that $\frac {\sin y} y \to 1$ as $y \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For $p=-1$, note that since $2x/\pi < \sin x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$, 
$$\frac{2}{\pi x} < \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
 for $x>\pi/2$, so 
$$\int_0^\infty \sin \frac{1}{x}\,dx \ge \int_0^\infty \frac{2}{\pi x}\,dx = \infty.$$